# Generate age from sql server. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Can you tell me how to get ages from 0-5 and so on from sql server and input the total in a textbox or label? please click the link for sample
[Generate Ages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHfIj.png)

thank you!

Comment: can we see your code? Moreover, can you be more explicit in your goal? I don't catch what you're willing to do...

Comment: for now i don't have yet code for this because i dunno how to start! 
sorry for my english. I want to get age for example from 1 - 5 or age from 6 -10 and sum them how many male and female in town1 in that particular age.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT age_column FROM your_table WHERE age_column BETWEEN '0' AND '5'"
'The above line selects the all records where age is between 0-5 (Change the variables)

Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connectionstring)
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt as new DataTable

da.Fill(ds)
dt = ds.Tables(0).Copy()

' Above code stores the results in an iterable table

Dim i As Integer = 0

For Each dr as DataRow in dt.Rows
i = i + 1
Next

TextBox1.Text = i

 'i will be the total number of records where age is between 0-5, and display it in a `TextBox`
```

Your question is, however, very poor, and normally people would not put too much effort into answering it, since you've put no effort in yourself.

Comment: Appreciated! and i'm sorry for my poor question because there's a small english vocabulary i have. I'll give this a shot!

Comment: @YevrahAradnop Do you already have a connection string that opens the connection? This is only if you're using `MS-Access` too, or you're using `OleDb` for another DBMS

Comment: The codes above is what i'm looking for. yes i already had a connection string but my problem was the codes like this. maybe i need some fresh air now. thank you so much!

Comment: Do it in SQL using COUNT and GROUP BY